# How to mock method call and return value without running the method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Consider the following method:

```
public boolean isACertainValue() {
        if(context.getValueA() != null && context.getValueA().toBoolean() == true) {
        if(context.getType() != null && context.getType() == ContextType.certainType) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I did not write this code, it is ugly as hell, it is totally overcomplicated but I have to work with it.

Now I want to test a method that relies on a call to this method.

I thought I could deal with this by:

`Mockito.when(spy.isACertainValue()).thenReturn(true);` because that's the case I want to test.

But it doesn't work as it is still calling the method-body :/

I get nullpointers or rather I get something along the lines of

> misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue; Boolean cannot be returned by getValueA().
>   getValueA() should return ValueA

So I tried (as a workaround) to do:

`Mockito.when(contextMock.getValueA()).thenReturn(new ValueA());`
and
`Mockito.when(contextMock.getType()).thenReturn(ContextType.certainType);`

but then I get a nullpointer that I cant seem to be able to debug.

So, how is it done right in this case?

Comment: That is exactly how to do it, but maybe there is a value IN that valueA you need further on in your test, so you should also mock the object returned, not just return an instance instantiated with a (default) constructor.

Comment: I had similar problem (a method in a super class was not mocked). The conclusion was that it was a bug in Mockito. Updating Mockito to 2.28.2 helped.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you are invoking

```
Mockito.when(spy.isCertainValue()).thenReturn(true);
```

the method `isCertainValue()` is getting called here. This is how Java works: to evaluate the argument of `Mockito.when`, the result of `spy.isCertainValue()` must be evaluated so the method must be called.

If you don't want that to happen, you can use [the following construct](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12):

```
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(spy).isCertainValue();
```

This will have the same mocking effect but the method won't be called with this.

Comment: Thank you, I'm more on track now... I get a nullpointer tho xD I hate this program so much, it's an abomination :X

Comment: Broken link. Where do you setup spy?

Comment: It worked for me. It stopped throwing NPE. Thanks Tunaki!

Comment: Do I have to run with **MockitoJUnitRunner** for this to work?

Comment: Imagine we have a aspect on this method. Then the aspect will be evaluated anyway. Do you have an idea how to bypass the aspect call ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me - Argument passed to when() is not a mock!

Comment: @skryvets just in case it isn't obvious: it seems that you're most likely passing in the real object and not a Spy/Mock of that object.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This code is correct:

```
Mockito.when(contextMock.getType()).thenReturn(ContextType.certainType);
```

But you are getting NullPointerException because you didn't define the Mocking value that should be defines, well I'm using Spring, in my context file when I define `@Autowired` bean I define it this way:

```
<bean id="contextMock" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.example.myspringproject.bean.ContextMock" />
</bean>
```