# Mockito when().thenReturn() throws nullpointerExceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to use Mockito to create a Mock object that gets returned from a Mock object. Specifically, I'm trying to mock a `PlayerConnection` object that my program can use to retrieve an IP address.

You can find more about this `PlayerConnection object` [here](https://jd.spongepowered.org/5.0.0/overview-summary.html). It returns an `InetSocketAddress` which can then return an `InetAddress` that can return a `String` with the IP of the player. But I can't get that far, because my first `when(class.function()).thenReturn(returnVariable)` throws a `NullPointerException`. Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Creates a partial mock of a connection that can return an ip address.
 * 
 * @param String
 *            The IP to return when the connection gets asked.
 * @return
 */
private PlayerConnection newConnection(String ipString)
{
    PlayerConnection playerConnection = mock(PlayerConnection.class);
    InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = mock(InetSocketAddress.class);
    InetAddress inetAddress = mock(InetAddress.class);

    when(playerConnection.getAddress()).thenReturn(inetSocketAddress);
    when(inetSocketAddress.getAddress()).thenReturn(inetAddress);
    when(inetAddress.getHostAddress()).thenReturn(ipString);

    return playerConnection;
}
```

And here's the stack trace, occuring at `when(playerConnection.getAddress()).thenReturn(inetSocketAddress)`:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec <<< FAILURE!
ruleResponseTest(com.github.heartsemma.communitywall.ConnectionChecks.RuleManagerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress$InetSocketAddressHolder.access$500(InetSocketAddress.java:56)
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.getAddress(InetSocketAddress.java:334)
        at com.github.heartsemma.communitywall.ConnectionChecks.RuleManagerTest.newConnection(RuleManagerTest.java:99)
        at com.github.heartsemma.communitywall.ConnectionChecks.RuleManagerTest.ruleResponseTest(RuleManagerTest.java:44)
```

Edit:

I have switched my stubs to `doReturn().when().function()` instead of `when().thenReturn()` to stop the `NullPointerExceptions`, and it did, but now I am getting custom `UnfinishedStubbingExceptions` from Mockito.

The helpful error code says that I have an unfinished stub somewhere, but I don't see where it is. The error occurs on the second `doReturn()` method.

```
/**
 * Creates a partial mock of a connection that can return an ip address.
 * 
 * @param ipString The IP to return.
 *            
 * @return A PlayerConnection object that can return a Host Address of the ipString but nothing else.
 */
private PlayerConnection newConnection(String ipString)
{
    PlayerConnection playerConnection = mock(PlayerConnection.class);
    InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = mock(InetSocketAddress.class);
    InetAddress inetAddress = mock(InetAddress.class);

    doReturn(inetSocketAddress).when(playerConnection).getAddress();
    doReturn(inetAddress).when(inetSocketAddress).getAddress();
    doReturn(ipString).when(inetAddress).getHostAddress();

    return playerConnection;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308877/how-to-mock-method-call-and-return-value-without-running-the-method.

Comment: I don't understand. You have the same error, and the same answer is to use `doReturn(inetSocketAddress).when(playerConnection).getAddress()` like mentioned, and you're not doing that (so how can you tell it didn't help?).

Comment: Sorry; What I meant to say was that it caused another error. Editing original post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Summary:** `InetSocketAddress.getAddress()` is final, [as listed in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#getAddress()). Due to its clever syntax, Mockito can't easily stub or verify `final` methods, and can't even tell you when it's trying and failing. In general, don't mock objects you don't control, particularly because of situations like this one.

The helpful error code for UnfinishedStubbingException identifies your problem (see option #2, you naughty developer!):

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at 

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

---

**Details:** Conventional Mockito mocks work by taking an object and automatically and silently generating a subclass where all the methods are overridden to delegate to Mockito. However, the Java compiler takes advantage of static dispatch for final methods, so calls to final methods don't go directly to Mockito, they go to the real method implementation in InetSocketAddress instead. This subclass instance isn't ever intended to be interacted with, and doesn't have any of its fields set, so it's very easy to get NullPointerException or other behavior—and all of this happens before you interact with Mockito, so you don't even get the benefit of a sane error message when using `when(object.methodCall()).thenReturn()`, because the unexpected NPE happens while evaluating `object.methodCall()` before Mockito gets involved at all.

Doing things the other way—`doReturn(...).when(object).methodCall()`—gives Mockito the chance to see `doReturn` and `when` even if the call to `methodCall` doesn't delegate to Mockito. This gives Mockito the context to say that the stubbing is unfinished, because Mockito can't see the `methodCall` call.

For more information, see this SO question ([Final method mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3793791/1426891)) and consider using the recent [opt-in mocking of final classes and methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods) that Mockito introduced in version 2.1.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I didn't realize InetSocketAddress.getAddress() was final.

Comment: Nice question, nice answer!